# How to split a hash based on values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, frequency

I have a hash in Ruby that is storing the word frequency of a string, with the word as the key and the frequency as the value.

```
words = a_string.split(/ /)
freqs = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| freqs[word] += 1 }
freqs = freqs.sort_by {|x,y| y }
freqs.reverse!
freqs.each do |word, freq|
    puts word+' '+freq.to_s
end
```

I've read that hash iterators return the hash in a random order, but this seems to work so far.

Now I need to freqs hash to only contain the 20 most frequent words. How can I do this? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've probably seen, the reason it stays sorted is because your call to [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120) changes your `Hash` into an `Array`. From the documentation for that method:

> The current implementation of sort_by generates an array of tuples containing the original collection element and the mapped value.

Once you have your sorted array, you could just use [`Array#first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002164) to get the top 20:

```
top20 = freqs.first(20)
```

If you want, you could use `to_hash` on the result to return it back to a `Hash`, but it will no longer be sorted.